# What is the meaning of "Aum"?

Tags: mantras, worship, translation-request, terminology, etymology

I have heard that many saints saying aum when they are in meditation. Not only saints, but many *mantra*s like:

> *aum namah shivaya; aum sreekrishnaya namah*

have "aum" present in it.

**Questions**:

- What is the meaning of "aum"?
- What is the meaning of `aum namah shivAya, aum sree krishnAye namah`?

Comment: Are you asking for the meaning of om in second question as well? Because it looks like you are asking for the meaning of whole manta.

Comment: yes, Krishna Shweta

Comment: @KrishnaShweta ^^^

Comment: Since the Qn is already closed as duplicate, it will be better to ask the meaning of Mantra-s in a separate post. BTW, since you already have the meaning of the "aum", you may easily derive mantra meanings. "namah" means to bow down with reverence and then the name of the deity. Anyways, I am rolling back to the original duplicate version. @Sarvabhouma, let the Sanskrit "aum" be present in the text. The OP wanted the symbol of image, hence I included "" and removed the image.

Comment: @iammilind nogshine told me to delete that simileys

Comment: @iammilind Many users see it as rectangles. That is why I asked him to remove the emoticon. It harms the uniformity. Also the revision has irrelevant tags. Some users can see and some can't. There are many users with chrome or text based browsers.  It looks like rectangle.  I also see some rectangles in your comment. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GWx3C.png

Comment: I am not able to see any smileys in my PC. I see the "" symbol. Earlier there was a big image, which was distracting. So at few places, I put that symbol. @Sarvabhouma, Is that looking rectangle in PC or mobile? I have hardly observed such ill-formatting for the non-English symbols.

Comment: @iammilind That emoticon which I think is om is visible to the users who use some types of browsers. I am not the only one. There are many users who have problem seeing emoticons. So, using text like "aum" is correct because every user should install emoji pack to see the question.

Comment: Yes @iammilind , Sarvabhouma is right. I too faced it many times. These emoticons are not supported for some.

Comment: @Akash Remove Aum emoticon

Comment: Akash b. You can use this- ॐ . Copy paste it, it is  a unicode symbol.